# Caption. Both left aligned and with bold font of Fig number

Tags: fonts, captions, bold

I have looked around to see if there is a way to both left align captions to the pictures width, make the Fig number bold and of course be able to reference the picture. I have only come across solutions that does part of it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is what I have done:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{grffile} %My path contains spaces
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {/Mypath/} }
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
                  singlelinecheck = false}
    \usepackage{threeparttable, floatrow}
    \usepackage{boxhandler}
    \newsavebox
    \mysavebox



    \begin{document}

First example is how the caption should look. Bold Fig name, normal text font, left align and with width of picture. However, the \ref{fig:Latex} does not work...

\begin{center}
\begin{measuredfigure} \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{Figures/LaTex}
%\decoRule
\caption[Stock Prices]{Looks beautiful. If only I could link to it???}
\label{fig:Latex}
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{center}


Next example I can refer to: \ref{fig:1stone} however, the caption is not what I'm looking for. It is left align and the width of the picture but not with bold Fig name and also a bit shifted. 

\begin{center}
\bxfigure[h]{\label{fig:1stone}I can link to this, however the font in the caption is not right.}{
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{Figures/Einstein}
}
\end{center}


\end{document}][1]][1]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Something seems to have gone wrong with formatting the code in your question, all `[` and `]` characters have a backslash in front. Or is this intentional? In any case, if you want to edit the question you can press the small `edit` link below the post.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a standard `figure` environment and set the width of the caption with `\captionsetup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  labelfont=bf ,
  justification = raggedright,
  singlelinecheck = false
}

\begin{document}

First example is how the caption should look. Bold Fig name, normal text
font, left align and with width of picture. However, the \ref{fig:Latex}
does not work...

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=0.5\columnwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{Figures/LaTex}
  \caption[Stock Prices]{Looks beautiful. If only I could link to it?}
  \label{fig:Latex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]